# "psycopg2.OperationalError" - I connect through pgadmin without any problems, and through psycopg2

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, psycopg2

The container is deployed in the docker. I've tried different ways, nothing helps. What could be the problem?  Could something from the outside be creating a problem?

```yaml
services:
    db:
      container_name: "db"
      image: postgres:14.1-alpine
      restart: always
      environment:
          - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
          - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
          - POSTGRES_DB=postgres
          - POSTGRES_PORT=5432
          - POSTGRES_HOST=db
          - POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD=trust
          - PGDATA=/var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata
      ports:
          - "5432:5432"
      networks:
          - custom
```

```py
db_name = 'postgres'
db_user = 'postgres'
db_password = 'postgres'
db_host = 'db'

conn =psycopg2.connect(dbname=db_name, user=db_user, password=db_password, host=db_host)
```

I've tried it

```
import psycopg2

# Параметры подключения к базе данных PostgreSQL
db_name = 'postgres'
db_user = 'postgres'
db_password = 'postgres'
db_host = 'db'

conn =psycopg2.connect(dbname=db_name, user=db_user, password=db_password, host=db_host)

# Создание курсора для выполнения SQL запросов
cursor = conn.cursor()

# Пример выполнения запроса SELECT
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM users")

# Получение результатов запроса
rows = cursor.fetchall()

# Вывод результатов
for row in rows:
    print(row)

# Закрытие курсора и соединения
cursor.close()
conn.close()
```

Result

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Мои проекты\pythonProject\db\conect.py", line 48, in <module>
    conn =psycopg2.connect(dbname=db_name, user=db_user, password=db_password, host=db_host)
  File "C:\Мои проекты\pythonProject\.venv\lib\site-packages\psycopg2\__init__.py", line 122, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)       
psycopg2.OperationalError
```

There are no lags, this is most annoying. I will be extremely grateful.

Comment: Are you sure that's the full error message?  I would have expected it to say some actual detail about the error, i.e. wrong username/password, wrong hostname, etc.

Comment: Yes, absolutely. But I realized that I'm not even finding the host through Pycharm or Visual studio. Yes, through the browser, but it doesn't work through psycopg2. Why is this so, maybe you know

Comment: Is your python code running in the `db` container, or a different container?

Comment: No, I'm running the code on a computer without docker. In the docker only db.

Comment: I think that's the problem.  The hostname `db` is only visible/accessible to other services inside the docker-compose network.  Your real computer can't access it.

Comment: It's a common practice, isn't it? Or do I need to fix something?

Answer (score 0):

Like other's stated already, `db` can (and should) be used as the hostname only in inter-container communication, it's not visible as the container hostname on your host machine.

Instead, when connecting from the host machine to the database container, you use `localhost`. That's why the `ports` part is needed too, you publish the port `5432` to be available outside to your host machine. And that really is the common practice here.

Even better would be to use `"127.0.0.1:5432:5432"` to really publish it only to the localhost. Currently it is open outside of your host machine too.

Comment: db_name = 'postgres'
db_user = 'postgres'
db_password = 'postgres'
db_host = 'localhost'

conn =psycopg2.connect(dbname=db_name, user=db_user, password=db_password, host=db_host, port='5432')
And how do I write this if connect is waiting for int data

Comment: Int data? `port=5432`? Host for sure is not an integer.